# XPages application crashed - only compiled Java files left

Tags: java, xpages

Can I restore my XPages and Customcontrols from the .java-files somehow?

I doubt it, but I have to ask.

Thanks!

/J

Comment: Do you have more details on the nature of the crash?

Comment: I cleaned the project and it started deleting files and I could see in the status that it started deleted XSP and customcontrol elements.

Comment: Very odd, as clean project can't do that. It doesn't delete design elements. Something like FIXUP might. I see you have a solution. I was going to suggest NotesPeek to see if you could find the elements. I'd recommend source control going forward though.

Comment: Yes, I have source control enabled. But the other dev doesn't... He made changes when I was away and those changes where erased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to go in package explorer to where the java files should show up. Then right click folder and choose the refresh action which hopefully will read the files in the project again.

You could also try to remove the NSF from workspace and open it again.

Comment: That, in combination with the local history of another dev saved virtually everything!
Thanks!